# How to use a remote wmts and generate its tiles in mapbox

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

according to [How to implement a tile source to mapbox-gl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577919/how-to-implement-a-tile-source-to-mapbox-gl/48581343#48581343) i have an issue on a raster tile source in mapbox gl JS, which probably seems to fit to your declaration that mapbox only supports x/y/z and not lat/lon tile coordinates. I've trouble on this with the following tile source (WMTS): https://www.wmts.nrw.de/geobasis/wmts_nw_dop20/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml.

I want to include this wmts as source and add as layer like this:

```
map.on("load", function() {

map.addSource("wmts-layer", {
            "type": "raster",
            "tiles":['https://www.wmts.nrw.de/geobasis/wmts_nw_dop20/tiles/nw_dop20/EPSG_3857_16/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpeg'],
            "tileSize": 256

        });
        map.addLayer({
          "id": "wmts-layer",
          "source": "wmts-layer",
          "type": "raster",
          "visibility": "visible",
          "source-layer": "nw_dop20",
        });
    });
```

it does not work at all, Tiles get loaded but are empty images! 
Can anyone point out whats the problem here?
cheers phil

Comment: Here is my example as code:  https://jsbin.com/nozoval/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using Mapbox-GL-JS correctly (although you don't need `source-layer`). For whatever reason, that service is returinng blank tiles [for example](https://www.wmts.nrw.de/geobasis/wmts_nw_dop20/tiles/nw_dop20/EPSG_3857_16/10/539/345.jpeg).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for investigation Steve,

this is really weird and for some reason the service seems to be unusable in mapbox gl as it serves different coordinates on each zoomlevel than it is specified in the tilescheme of mapbox (tms or xyz)!

see:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/6089